# PDF Report Viewer in Chrome displays actual project filename

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-extensions

In the latest version of Chrome, when a PDF report gets downloaded and displayed in the browser from our web application, the actual project filename appears on the PDF toolbar. Is there a way to remove this or just display the report filename set in the content disposition (also seen in the browser URL) instead? Please see attachment for reference.

Report being generated using Report Definition Language Client (RDLC).
Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106[image: Sample image]

Comment: What does RDLC mean?

Comment: How are you creating/generating the PDF's in the first place?  What program is making the PDFs?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like this in the web API..

```
var data = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource(dataSourceName, dataSource);
string mimeType;

var report = new ReportBuilder()
            .ReportPath(reportPath)
            .DataSource(data)
            .Build(ReportFormat.Pdf);

var bytes = report.Render(out mimeType);

var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "FilenameSetInContentDisposition",
        Inline = false,
    };

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());

return this.File(bytes, mimeType);
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more ?